# swagger-parsser@3.4.1 webpack compile issue

Tags: angular, swagger

I have installed `swagger-parser@3.4.1`  and trying to validate my api using parser.validate("swaggerJson") as per documents found [here](https://github.com/BigstickCarpet/swagger-parser/tree/master/docs) but getting webpack compile issue

Here is the code ...

```
SwaggerParser = require('swagger-parser');
validateResult: string;
swaggerSpec ;

constructor(private http: Http, private service: DifferencesService){
  let  parser = new this.SwaggerParser();
  service.getSwaggerSpec().subscribe(
    result => { this.swaggerSpec = result;},
    error => { console.log(error); }
  );
  parser.validate(this.swaggerSpec).then(function(api) {
    this.validateResult = "Yay! The API is valid.";
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
   this.validateResult = 'Onoes! The API is invalid. ' + err.message;
  });
```

Here is the Error ...

```
ERROR in ./~/swagger-parser/lib/validate-schema.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'swagger-schema-official/schema' in 'D:\gitmyworkspace\mywork\pcfdeploy\node_modules\swagger-parser\lib'
@ ./~/swagger-parser/lib/validate-schema.js 6:20-61
@ ./~/swagger-parser/lib/index.js
@ ./src/app/components/swagger-validate.component.ts
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200/ ./src/main.ts
ERROR in ./~/swagger-parser/lib/promise.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'es6-promise' in 'D:\gitmyworkspace\mywork\pcfdeploy\node_modules\swagger-parser\lib'
@ ./~/swagger-parser/lib/promise.js 4:59-81
@ ./~/swagger-parser/lib/index.js
@ ./src/app/components/swagger-validate.component.ts
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200/ ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./~/json-schema-ref-parser/lib/promise.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'es6-promise' in 'D:\gitmyworkspace\mywork\pcfdeploy\node_modules\json-schema-ref-parser\lib'
@ ./~/json-schema-ref-parser/lib/promise.js 4:59-81
@ ./~/json-schema-ref-parser/lib/index.js
@ ./~/swagger-parser/lib/index.js
@ ./src/app/components/swagger-validate.component.ts
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200/ ./src/main.ts
webpack: Failed to compile.
```